# How to use a Java .dll in C# .NET Core 6?

Tags: java, c#, .net-core, dll, ikvm

## Initial situation

I've made a little test for my project today - The goal: Implement `.jar` files into a `C#` project as a `.dll`. My current `.java` / `.jar` file looks like the following.

```
package ws;

public class Adding
{
    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

I successfully converted the above into a `.dll` with [IKVM](https://www.windwardstudios.com/blog/ikvm-is-alive-well) (Version: 7.5.0.2).

I now want to reference this `.dll` in my `C#` project and call the `Add(int a, int b)` method. I already added the reference like so:

[image]

Anyways I am not able to call the method, because the compiler can't find the `.dll` reference..

```
using Adding; // <= Compiler Error CS0246 (Can't find the reference)

Console.WriteLine(Add(1, 2));
```

Does anybody know how I could achieve this? I highly appreciate any kind of help, cheers!

---

## Edit 1: Decompiling

I've decompiled the `.dll`, as demanded in the comments, with [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) (Version: ILSpy 7.2), which results into the following output.

```
// C:\Users\maikh\Desktop\Adding.dll
// Adding, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// Global type: <Module>
// Architecture: AnyCPU (64-bit preferred)
// Runtime: v4.0.30319
// Hash algorithm: SHA1

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using IKVM.Attributes;

[assembly: Debuggable(true, false)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.0.0.0")]
[module: SourceFile(null)]
[module: JavaModule(Jars = new string[] { "Adding.jar" })]
[module: PackageList(new string[] { })]
```

I've also found some references, while decompiling the `.dll`. I don't know if this is important to mention, but I'll provide it anyways.

```
// Detected TargetFramework-Id: .NETFramework,Version=v4.0
// Detected RuntimePack: Microsoft.NETCore.App

// Referenced assemblies (in metadata order):
// IKVM.Runtime, Version=7.5.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=00d957d768bec828
    // Assembly reference loading information:
    // There were some problems during assembly reference load, see below for more information!
    // Error: Could not find reference: IKVM.Runtime, Version=7.5.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=00d957d768bec828

// mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    // Assembly reference loading information:
    // Info: Success - Found in Assembly List



// Assembly load log including transitive references:
// IKVM.Runtime, Version=7.5.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=00d957d768bec828
    // Error: Could not find reference: IKVM.Runtime, Version=7.5.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=00d957d768bec828

// mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    // Info: Success - Found in Assembly List
```

---

## Edit 2: Decompiling V2

I've managed to add the missing reference `IKVM.Runtime`. Nevertheless I can't find any informations about the namespace, class or method.

[image]

Comment: Try decompiling the DLL to C# with a tool like ILSpy. Seeing the C# code will help people diagnose your issue.

Comment: You seem to have a missing reference to "IKVM.Runtime", that will need to be fixed, but should only cause runtime errors. You should have your Adding class in the ILSpy menu tree for the assembly, that would be relevant to include if you still get compiler errors.

Comment: @JonasH I've no experience with ILSpy or decompiling in general - How do I add the Adding class in the menu tree for the assembly? Thanks already

Comment: You should not have to add anything. The tree for the assembly should expand into namespaces, classes, methods etc... If you cannot find your class in the tree then something is wrong with the conversion. Or at least, the produced assembly cannot be used as a regular .net assembly.  See [ILSpy Screenshots from store page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ilspy/9mxfbkfvsq13?activetab=pivot:overviewtab#)

Comment: @JonasH I've managed to add the missing reference "IKVM.Runtime". Nevertheless I can't find the namespace, class, method etc... (see the edit #2)

Comment: I can't help you with that, as I'm not familiar with IKVM.

Comment: Did you try with IKVM 8.5? And what version of Java did you use to compile the jar?

Comment: I didn't managed to convert my `.jar` with the 8.5.0.2 Version, but I've tried it with the [newest version of IKVM](https://github.com/jessielesbian/ikvm/releases/tag/v8.6.9.0_RC6) I could find. Nevertheless same problem. I am using Java 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you are using a class as a namespace, and that is probably not correct. Your method call should probably look something like this:

```
var adder = new Adding();
Console.WriteLine(adder.Add(1, 2));
```

If that does not work I would [inspect the produced dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/view-contents) to verify that it is a conforming .net dll. That should also show the namespaces, class names and other information. A decompiler like dotPeek or ilSpy might show the same information in a format that may be easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Since your Java class is in the `ws` package, you should be `using ws` in your C# code:

```cs
using ws;

Adding adding = new Adding();
Console.WriteLine(adding.Add(1, 2));
```

And if you want to call the `Add` method statically, declare it `static` in Java:

```java
package ws;

public class Adding
{
    public static int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

```cs
using ws;

Console.WriteLine(Adding.Add(1, 2));
```

Comment: Thank for asking about my Java verison - Just found out that my private computer hasn't installed Java... No wonder why it is not working. It's strange that IKVM doesn't throw any error. Long story short it is working now. Anyways I do have new problems to solve now^^ I don't know if you want to make a suitable answer for the Java problem? - So I can mark it as helpful. Small reminder never switch between working computer and private computer^^